# How to change / convert values in Output that comes from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a view in my SQL Server database which will give me number of columns.

One of the column heading is `Priority` and the values in this column are `Low`, `Medium`, `High` and `Immediate`.

When I execute this view, the result is returned perfectly like below. I want to change or assign values for these priorities. For example: instead of `Low` I should get 4, instead of `Medium` I should get 3, for `High` it should be 2 and for `Immediate` it should be 1.

What should I do to achieve this?

```
Ticket#   Priority
123       Low
1254      Low
5478      Medium
4585      High
etc.,     etc.,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

> Instead of Low I should get 4, instead of Medium I should get 3, for
>   High it should be 2 and for Immediate it should be 1

```
SELECT 
  [Ticket#],
  [Priority] = CASE Priority
                 WHEN 'Low'       THEN 4
                 WHEN 'Medium'    THEN 3
                 WHEN 'High'      THEN 2
                 WHEN 'Immediate' THEN 1
                 ELSE NULL
               END
FROM table_name;
```

**EDIT:**

If you use dictionary table like in [George Botros Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679638/5070879) you need to remember about:

1) Maintaining and storing dictionary table

2) Adding `UNIUQE` index to `Priority.Name` to avoid duplicates like:

```
Priority table
--------------------
Id  |  Name | Value
--------------------
1   |  Low  | 4
2   |  Low  | 4
...
```

3) Instead of `INNER JOIN` defensively you ought to use `LEFT JOIN` to get all results even if there is no corresponding value in dictionary table.

Comment: While casing works, joining a separate table, as in @GeorgeBotros solution is often preferable, because revisiting the definitive source later doesn't require you to go find all your case statements and adjust.

Comment: @Clay As always it depends. 1) Using separate table I need to store it somewhere and maintain it 2) Make sure that Priority.Name is `UNIQUE` 3) What if there is no corresponding value (`LEFT JOIN` needed)

Comment: agreed on all points - I had hoped you would elaborate. It serves everybody's interests.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution for your problem by creating a new Priority table (Id, Name, Value)
by joining to this table you will be able to select the value column

```
SELECT Ticket.*, Priority.Value 
FROM Ticket INNER JOIN Priority 
ON Priority.Name = Ticket.Priority
```

Note: although using the `case` keyword is the most straight forward solution for
this problem
this solution may be useful if you will need this priority value in many places at your system